# How do I build an array of arrays in a for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to build the `matrix` array using one or more for loops, but I'm not quite grasping how to achieve the 'each row is itself enclosed in an array' via building it with loops

```js
var matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
];

var loopMatrix = []
var columns = 5
var rows = 3
for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    var index = x * y
    if ((x == 3 && y == 0) || (x == 4 && y == 1) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 2 && y == 2)) {
      loopMatrix.push(1)
    } else {
      loopMatrix.push(0)
    }
  }
}

console.log(matrix) 
console.log(loopMatrix) // should be identical to matrix
```

Comment: It would be an array of arrays.  that way you would reference:   `loopmatrix[x][y]` . Your code never creates a new entry into the outter loop.  You can DO It your way, but it is very C-esque, where you are seeking by length of a row... (5 cells)

Comment: If you find an answer which suits your needs, feel free to mark it accordingly.  Have a great day

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code:

```
var matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
];

var loopMatrix = []
var columns = 5
var rows = 3
for (var x = 0; x < columns; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < rows; y++) {
    var index = x * y
    if ((x == 3 && y == 0) || (x == 4 && y == 1) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 2 && y == 2)) {
      loopMatrix.push(1)
    } else {
      loopMatrix.push(0)
    }
  }
}

console.log(matrix) 
console.log(loopMatrix) // should be identical to matrix
```

Here is my answer:

```
var matrix = [
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
    [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
    [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
];

var loopMatrix = []
var columns = 5
var rows = 3
for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {   // swapped rows with columns.
  loopMatrix.push([]) // Added a new array instance here.
  for (var y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
    var index = x * y
    if ((x == 3 && y == 0) || (x == 4 && y == 1) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 2 && y == 2)) {
      loopMatrix[x].push(1) // reference x here because it exists by this point in the execution.
    } else {
      loopMatrix[x].push(0)  // reference x here because it exists by this point in the execution.
    }
  }
}

console.log(matrix) 
console.log(loopMatrix) // should be identical to matrix
```

When you see my answer, The difference is that I looped it BY ROW and also pushed this X.   I kept all of your code and guts the same.  The reason why it works is that since X is 0->N it will have an entry into that part of the array, so it wont have any index out of bounds errors.

Based on my solution, you can easily reference it now by: `loopMatrix[row][col]` where row/col, are 0-indexed

Comment: This is a nice way. I didn't think about this. `:)`

Comment: Thanks.  I wanted to keep his guts the same as much as possible and give the solution which would work with him.  I wouldnt mind cleaning it up a little more, but i dont know the scope of the answer.  Sometimes people give snippets or half the data, so i wanted to let him come to the conclusion himself based on his needs.

Comment: Thanks, the first critical insight was to first loop by `rows` like you did, since I need each row to be its own array, looping by `columns` first got me stuck.

Answer (score 0):

You should be building an array of arrays. I don't think you need to use `index` anywhere. I followed this:

1. If the current row is not defined, define it to an array.
2. Set the value as 1 if it's in one of our targets.
3. Else, set it to 0.

This is the main code you need to be aware of:

```
var index = x * y;
if (typeof loopMatrix[x] == "undefined")
  loopMatrix[x] = [];
if ((x == 3 && y == 0) || (x == 4 && y == 1) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 2 && y == 2)) {
  loopMatrix[x][y] = 1;
} else {
  loopMatrix[x][y] = 0;
}
```

Full code here:

```js
var matrix = [
  [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
];

var loopMatrix = [];
var columns = 5;
var rows = 3;
for (var x = 0; x < rows; x++) {
  for (var y = 0; y < columns; y++) {
    var index = x * y;
    if (typeof loopMatrix[x] == "undefined")
      loopMatrix[x] = [];
    if ((x == 3 && y == 0) || (x == 4 && y == 1) || (x == 0 && y == 1) || (x == 2 && y == 2)) {
      loopMatrix[x][y] = 1;
    } else {
      loopMatrix[x][y] = 0;
    }
  }
}

console.log(matrix);
console.log(loopMatrix);
```

The above code will give you:

```
matrix     = [[0, 0, 0, 1, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
loopMatrix = [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you just want to have another identical array just use slice methode

```
var matrix = [
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0]];

var loopMatrix = matrix.slice();
```

[check slice documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

```
var matrix = [
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
];

var loopMatrix = []
var columns = 5
var rows = 3


for ( var x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++)
{
    for(var y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++)
    { 
   put your logic here that will set your 1's and 0's
   such as if x = 0 and y = 3 then make it a 1

   if (index === 3 || index === 5 || index === 9 || index === 12) {
     loopMatrix.push(1)
   } else {
     loopMatrix.push(0)
   }
}
} 


console.log(matrix) 
console.log(loopMatrix) // should be identical to matrix
```

Comment: No explanation?